# I’m confused on what to fill out with the code to roll these 2 dice and keep the highest of the 2 numbers

Tags: java

```
public class RollTheDice {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
                      int die1;
                      int die2;
                      int roll;

                      die1 = (int)(Math.random() *6) + 1;
                      die2 = (int)(Math.random() *6) + 1;
                      roll = die1 + die2;

                      System.out.println(“First number is……” + die1);
                      System.out.println(“The second number is……” + die2);
            }
}
```

I tried some things but none of them worked whatsoever but I can’t figure out how to complete the code to fully try it

Comment: You said "keep the highest of the 2 numbers", so there needs to be some sort of comparison somewhere.

Comment: Are you aware how the `if` and `if ... else` statement works? If not I would recommend reading a [Tutorial about those statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)  and a [Tutorial about conditional statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 2):

//just add an if Statement

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                 int die1;
                 int die2;
                 int roll;

                 die1 = (int)(Math.random() *6) + 1;
                 die2 = (int)(Math.random() *6) + 1;
                 roll = die1 + die2;

                 System.out.println("First number is……" + die1);
                 System.out.println("The second number is……" + die2);
   
        if (die1>=die2) {
            System.out.println("The highest dice number is " + die1);
        }else {
            System.out.println("The highest dice number is " + die2);
        }
}
```

}